# Analytics Universal and subdomains

Tags: google-analytics

I have page A on domain linkody.com that sends to page B on subdomain bc.linkody.com.
Since I switched to Universal analytics, the bounce rate when to the roof.

It looks to me like both pages are counted as 2 different sessions.

Most of the users land to page A, see page B and stop there. So if page B is not counted as the same session, that would explain why page A bounce rate is insane.

The documentation specifies:

> Tracking users across subdomains does not require any additional configuration.

So, what's wrong here?

PS:

Page A is http://www.linkody.com/en/seo-tools/free-backlink-checker.
When a domain is entered, the form sends to (for example): http://bc.linkody.com/en/seo-tools/free-backlink-checker/linkody.com

Comment: To test your assumption, did you look into the landing page report  to see if there are a lot of entrances at bc.linkody.com ? Your code is correct, though (and since sessions in UA are maintained serverside there is not much you could have done wrong). It might be a good idea to check if your domain is in the referral exclusion list in the property settings (if it isn't your problem might be caused by self-referals, so check traffic sources for bc.linkody.com).

Comment: Most of the entrances to bc.linkody.com come from www.linkody.com (which is excluded from referrals by definition).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was just to add both domains (main and subdomain) to the Referral Exclusion List.
So the main domain was counted as referral for the subdomain, which in my view does not make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

The best explanation is on the [Google Analytics documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/domains) but I'll try to make a summary.

There are two ways to implement your tracking, the simplest one requires you to allow [Automatic Cookie Domain Configuration](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/domains#auto) adding the auto parameter to the ga constructor.

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', 'auto');
```

The second solution requires you to configure all trackers to set a cookie at the highest domain possible, here an [example](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/domains#multitrackers):

```
// Configuration for bc.linkody.com
ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', {'cookieDomain': 'linkody.com'});
```

Comment: I'm already passing the auto parameter to the ga constructor.

Comment: Have you tried [Google Analytics Debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna)? I tried to debug the example pages you posted but everything seems ok...